# PowerShell Remoting BinaryFormatter serialization

Tags: powershell, .net-framework-version, asp.net-core-5.0

I am using PowerShell from a .Net Core 5.0 webapi. It seems there is an [security issue with the BinaryFormatter](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14032). Does anyone know if this issue also exists in .Net Framework 4.7.2?

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` has been deprecated because it's easily convinced to execute code it shouldn't if fed data from an untrusted source. This is a fundamental issue with how it works, not specific to the implementation in .NET Core, so in that sense it also exists in .NET Framework (all versions). See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide) for background info. Of course, in some cases you can't get around legacy technology that still uses it, and that may be OK if in fact you can trust the input.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert, Your comment is a viable answer however I am not able to mark it as such. I don't know why.

Comment: Because comments are not answers, only answers are answers. You're not supposed to answer questions in comments, but I often do it anyway because my standards for answers are far higher than the site's and I would have to spend much more time thinking about it. Fortunately anyone (including the person who asked the question) is free to take my comment, post it as an answer and take all the credit, even though most people don't do this because it makes them feel uneasy. Decisions, decisions. :P